# how get to an azure table list per month?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to make a query on my azure table but I can't return anything, it's giving an error 400, as if the query was wrong.

on azure table the pattern I enter is this:

PartitionKey | RowKey | timestamp | Date | Quantidade| Observacao | ClientID | FuncionarioID

the timestamp is default: ex: 2021-06-16T18:20:00.000Z, but I don't know how to get only the month of timestamp.

follow the code below:

```
public List<Producao> ConsultarProducao(int mes, string funcionarioId)
    {
        try
        {
            string query = "Timestamp.DateTime.Month eq '" + mes + "' and FuncionarioID='" + funcionarioId + "'";
            CloudTableClient storageTransfer = GetTableClient();
            CloudTable table = storageTransfer.GetTableReference("producao");

            var lista = table.CreateQuery<Producao>().Where(
            y => y.Timestamp.DateTime.Month == mes && y.FuncionarioID == funcionarioId
            ).ToList();




            return lista;
        }
        catch (Exception ExceptionObj)
        {

            throw ExceptionObj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `error 404`? where? in browser? then it is basically you are accessing wrong url. I'm not sure if azure have an error code 404 at all.

Comment: it enters the catch and the error is: "The remote serve returned an error: (400) Bad request", sorry the error is 400

Comment: The problem is indeed with your query. You can't filter by month like the way you're doing it currently. Please edit your question and provide more details regarding what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: How's going?Has your issue got resolveD?

Answer (score 0):

Just try the code below to filter all items that `Timestamp` in June：

```
        var connStr = "<storage connection string>";
        var tableName = "<your table name>";

        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connStr);
        CloudTableClient client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        var table = client.GetTableReference(tableName);

        var filter = "Timestamp ge datetime'2021-06-01T00:00:00Z' and Timestamp lt datetime'2021-07-01T00:00:00Z' ";

        var query = new TableQuery<Producao>().Where(filter);

        var queryResults = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
```